# Write LS equation with conditions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, rusle

I have two raster layers flowacc and slope. I want to calculate this equation with conditions into the ArcGIS raster calculator:

```
LS = power(flowacc * resolution/22.13),m)*(0.065+0.045*slope+0.0065*power(slope,2)) white 
m = 0.5 for s <5% 
m = 0.4 for 3% < s ≤ 5%   
m = 0.3 for 1% < s ≤ 3% 
m = 0.2 for s ≤ 1%.
```

How can I do this?